# MySQL Workbench: "SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : '(', WITH error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query which I have written in MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT
    t1.sample_id, t1.v_id, t1.s_type as type, t1.s_fusion, t1.e_fusion, CONCAT(t1.cpt1, ":", t1.ppt1) as point1,
    CONCAT(t1.cpt2, ":", t1.ppt2) as point2, t1.s_gene, t1.e_gene, t1.pscore as score, t2.manual_notes
FROM
(
    s_samples
    WHERE sample_id = 'S0001'
) as t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT c.v_id, c.sample_id,
    CONCAT(c.sample_id,"(",e.disease,"): ",c.notes) as manual_notes
    FROM all_samples e
    LEFT JOIN s_samples c
    ON e.sample_id=c.sample_id
    WHERE c.notes is not null AND c.v_id IN
    (SELECT v_id FROM s_samples)
    AND c.sample_id = 'S0001'
) as t2
ON t1.v_id = t2.v_id
ORDER BY t1.v_id;
```

However, I am getting the following error: "SELECT" is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting : '(', WITH error. I am relatively new to SQL so I am not sure why I am getting this error and how to resolve this. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid SQL:

```
FROM
(
    s_samples
    WHERE sample_id = 'S0001'
) as t1
```

Perhaps you intend:

```
FROM (SELECT s.*
      FROM s_samples s
      WHERE s.sample_id = 'S0001'
     ) t1
```

Of course, this is superfluous.  You can just use the table and put the filtering in an outer `WHERE` clause.

I think your error is caused by just some general confusion because the compiler is confused.

Comment: *"Of course, this is superfluous. You can just use the table and put the filtering in an outer WHERE clause"* Yes in this case i also think the best option is indeed to rewrite the SQL.. As, i doubt in this case the optimizer is smart enough to factor out those subqueries on it as that `INNER JOIN (SELECT ...)` is also there as the more modern MySQL versions can do in some cases..